# Linear span- geometric interpretation in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that Span({$x$})={$ax: a\in F$} for any vector $x$ in a vector space. Interpret this result geometrically in $\mathbb R^3$

My attempt at the first part:

By definition of Span, Span({$x$}) is the set that contains all linear combinations of $x$. So, for any $a\in F$, Span({$x$})={$ax: a\in F$}

I'm confused about the second part. I think it geometrically represents all the points on the $x$-axis.

Am I correct about both the parts?

Comment: Not necessarily: try a concrete example, with $x=(1,1,1)$. Is span($\{x\}$) the $x$-axis?

Comment: The first part is correct btw .

Comment: No. Then Span is all points coplanar with $x$?

Comment: The span is the line through the given vector.

Comment: I don't understand how. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: The span of $\{x\}$ is equal to the set $\{ax\}$ as you have proved: and this is precisely the set of points that lie on the line through the vector $x$ and the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See any vector space must contain the zero element. The geometrical equivalent of the span of $\{x\}$ is the line passing through $x$ and $0$